# Data structures or coding styles in C++ for avoiding long elseif chain when parsing?

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, parsing

Lately I have created some small parsers of data. My initial code structure

```
// more cases here ...
else if(!strcmp(X,"somekey")){
  // Parse according to "somekey" behavior.
}
// more cases here ...
```

worked fine for small number of parse cases, but the obvious drawback is that this soon grows into a huge if-elseif-else chain which is very ugly and non-modular and can be pain in the ass to debug if small errors sneak in somewhere.

A more modular C way of handling this could be done with function pointers.

```
for(int i = 0; i < NR_of_parse_cases; i++){
   if(!strcmp(X,lKey[i])){
     parseAs[i](X,data_to_parse);
     continue;
   }
}
```

Now we have made it more modular. We can populate two arrays with c-strings and corresponding pointers to functions without having to copy-paste or comment out huge chunks of code with all errors that could bring. But there are still several non-optimal things here. If inside for loop is ugly and also slow. I suspect there must be some more moder C++:y way to do this, maybe "maps" or something similar to python "dict" ?

Comment: Use a statemachine instead.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this sounds interesting. Feel free to explain how it works or give a link or reference.

Comment: E.g. [this one](http://www.eli.sdsu.edu/courses/spring96/cs596/notes/andrew/statemac.html), but there are tons of information if you just google _c++ parser state machine_. You can even generate one using _flex / bison_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using if–else is fine. Using a for–if is also fine, and will end up being similarly fast: the performance problem would be an indirect call through a function pointer, not that you're searching through an array.

But of course you can do better.

If the number if keys is very large (probably 100+) then it could make sense to use a hash table instead of looping through an array. However, use of pointer keys in a map requires care, you should likely consider `std::string` keys instead. I've also have good experiences with custom hash tables since they can be much more compact than the standard library variants.

If you're concerned with function call overhead, you could write a template function that generates your if–else structure, but enables the compiler to inline the handler code. The core insight is that indirect function calls (function pointers, virtual functions) cannot be inlined in general, but lambdas have an unique type that makes inlining fairly straightforward.

This would require some amount of template metaprogramming, e.g.

```cpp
template<class DefaultAction>
void parseCases(const char* token, DefaultAction&& defaultAction) {
  defaultAction();
}

template<class Action, class... Rest>
void parseCases(const char* token, const char* key, Action&& action, Rest&&... rest) {
  if (0 == strcmp(token, key)) action();
  else parseCases(token, std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
}

// usage:
const char* token = ...;
parseCases(
  token,
  "foo", []() { std::cout << "got a foo token" << std::endl; },
  "bar", []() { std::cout << "got a bar token" << std::endl; },
  []() { std::cout << "got something else" << std::endl; }
);
```

This should produce exactly the same code as manually writing the if–else structure, but is arguably easier to read and less error-prone to write. This also gives you the opportunity to more easily change the parsing strategy at a later point.

Comment: _"Using if–else is fine. Using a for–if is also fine ..."_ Yes, but it often leads to a mainenance nightmare.

Comment: I especially like how you mentioned hash function. I thought about that also. 
It would give constant time instead of linear time.

Comment: @mathreadler Yes, but constant time matters only for large data sets. Hash tables are *typically* slower than iterating through an array/vector because they need more pointers to be dereferenced (at least 2 pointers for std::unordered_map). Computers are very fast at scanning through stuff linearly, there are even native instructions for string comparisons! In Python this is less of a concern because everything is slow anyway.